# Replace text on the fly while typing in EMACS?

Tags: unicode, emacs, keystroke

I'm creating a major mode for editing Algol source files which are
written using Unicode characters.

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.a60\\'" . algol-mode))
```

I want to have the following behaviour when editing .a60 files:

As an example, when I type the two characters `<=` in succession, I want
them to be deleted and the Unicode character `≤` inserted instead.  But
only when typed in that order - if I typed `<` then a space. then erased
the space and typed `=`, I wouldn't want the replacement to happen - I would
expect to see an unaltered `<=`.  And to be clear I want this change to
be made to text I type - not existing text already in the file.  The
replacement text is to be inserted in the file as if it had been typed...
it is not just a replacement for display, like the way some language major
modes will underline keywords on the screen but not save the underlined
text in the file.

So `<=` was one trivial example - but what I actually want is a fully
general-purpose input text filter where I can define pairs of typed text
and replacement text in my language mode for .a60 files in .emacs,
eg something like

```
(subtitute "&&", "∧")
```

or

```
(subtitute "'begin'", "b̲e̲g̲i̲n̲")
```

I.e. I can define several replacements for things I can type, with unicode
text that I can't easily type.

And to reiterate, I don't want to type any escape characters of any sort -
I just want to key in a line of code such as `'if' a <= b 'then' explode;`
and have `i̲f̲ a ≤ b t̲h̲e̲n̲ explode;` entered into my file.

(I will be careful not to create definitions that could infinitely recurse.)
I naively tried using global-set-key but as you probably know (although I
didn't until I tried it) that only works for strings with certain prefix
characters.  I want this new mechanism to work with arbitrary text.
I don't think abbrev mode or flymake are what I'm looking for - those
were the closest similar solutions I could find in other postings here.

At the end of the day... I did try the abbrev solution suggested by Rorshach (and modifed by https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36890/alternative-to-abbrev-mode-that-supports-special-characters-in-abbreviations ) but couldn't make it work 100%.  I ended up using the following code:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.a60\\'" . a60-mode))

(defun a60-chars () "Convert Algol 60 symbols from ISO to Unicode."
  (interactive)
  (if (looking-back "<=") (progn (backward-delete-char 2) (insert "≤") )
  (if (looking-back ">=") (progn (backward-delete-char 2) (insert "≥") )
  ;; (if (looking-back "\\\\")  (progn (backward-delete-char 1) (insert "¬") )
  (if (looking-back "~")  (progn (backward-delete-char 1) (insert "¬") )
  (if (looking-back "&&") (progn (backward-delete-char 2) (insert "∧") )
  (if (looking-back "||") (progn (backward-delete-char 2) (insert "∨") )
  (if (looking-back "!=") (progn (backward-delete-char 2) (insert "≠") )
  (if (looking-back "==") (progn (backward-delete-char 2) (insert "≡") )
  (if (looking-back "*")  (progn (backward-delete-char 1) (insert "×") )
  ;; (if (looking-back "\\^")  (progn (backward-delete-char 1) (insert "↑") )
  (if (looking-back "<>") (progn (backward-delete-char 2) (insert "≠") )
  (if (looking-back "//") (progn (backward-delete-char 2) (insert "÷") )
)))))))))))

;; Only enable when editing .a60 files:
(add-hook 'a60-mode-hook
          '(lambda()
            (add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook #'a60-chars nil 'local)
            )
          t
)
```

I still have some small tweaking to do (to allow replacements for `^` and `\`) but basically the above does what I need.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: it sounds like `abbrev-mode` pretty much, except for not expanding after deleting.  You could probably get that behaviour by adding a custom expansion predictate though.  For example, if you didnt want the expansion, you could hit TAB to cycle back to the default

Comment: See `hippie-expand` for cycling behaviour

Comment: This is what I have so far, except it doesn't allow me to enter unfiltered "<=" when I need to: (defun a60-le ()
  "Convert <= to ≤"
  (interactive)
  (if (looking-back "<=")
      (progn
        (backward-delete-char 2)
        (insert "≤")
        )))
(add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook #'a60-le )

Comment: Rorshach - thanks, I didn't realise abbrev mode could work from a table of elisp definitions, I had mis-read it as needing to enter the definitions interactively.  (And the forced space after an abbrev is mildly annoying but I could easily live with that) However... although I think the abbrev mode is active (going by the modified window name) I can't get any replacements to happen other than the one '<=' I hard-coded myself using post-self-insert-hook.  I've updated my post above with the added code. Can you see something I might have broken?

Comment: Found the problem: Allowed Abbrev Characters
Abbrev word can contain letters and digits, and can start with a digit.
Abbrev cannot contain punctuation. (you cannot change this, it's part of C code.) - bit of a deal-killer :-(

Comment: you can get around that by adding a `post-self-insert-hook`.  I do that in some modes, for example I want abbrevs to expand after `)` in lisp code, I use something like `(defun my-abbrev-expand-after-symbols-hook ()
  (and (memq (car (syntax-after (1- (point)))) '(0 3))
       (setq this-command 'my-abbrev-expand-after-symbols)
       (expand-abbrev)))`

Comment: also, abbrevs can contain whatever you want them to, you just may need to modify the `:enable-function` or the `:regexp` properties or your abbrev tables.  Or customize the `abbrev-grab-symbol`- there are many ways to make them work like you want.  You can even let bind the syntax table around whatever command you are running.

Comment: Post above updated. I couldn't make the abbrev solution work so fell back to my roll-your-own hack invoked by a60-mode.  Crude but it works well enough. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: PS You can see the result of this exercise at https://gtoal.com/recordings/algol-editing.html ...